# Downloading s3 bucket to local directory but files not copying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

There are many, many examples of how to download a directory of files from an s3 bucket to a local directory.

`aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/<directory> /<path>/<to>/<local>/ --recursive`

However, I run this command from my AWS CLI that I've connected to and see confirmation in the terminal like:

```
download: s3://mybucket/myfolder/data1.json to /my/local/dir/data1.json
download: s3://mybucket/myfolder/data2.json to /my/local/dir/data2.json
download: s3://mybucket/myfolder/data3.json to /my/local/dir/data3.json
...
```

But then I check `/my/local/dir` for the files, and my directory is empty. I've tried using the `sync` command instead, I've tried copying just a single file - nothing seems to work right now. In the past I *did* successfully run this command and downloaded the files as expected.

Why are my files not being copied now, despite seeing no errors?

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can go to your `/my/local/dir` folder and execute following command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/myfolder .
```

Comment: From `/my/local/dir` I launched a terminal, connected to my AWS EC2 instance via ssh, ran this command (substituting actual directory names), received no error.

`/my/local/dir` is still empty.

Comment: Why do you connect to ssh instance? If you go to EC2 and lunch the command from there, files will be copied on EC2. So you have to setup aws-cli on your local machine, configure aws-cli and run the command locally without jumping on ec2

Comment: I am following the instruction on EC2 > Connect to instance > SSH client

Comment: So you should expect files will be downloaded on EC2, not on you local computer.